# Showing that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{in^2x}/{n^3}$ is absolutely continuous

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity, fourier-series, absolute-continuity

This [paper](http://matematicas.uam.es/%7Eantonio.cordoba/documentos/articulos/DifferentiabilityandDimension.pdf) claims that the function  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{2\pi in^kx}}{n^\alpha}$ is absolutely continuous if $\alpha > k+\frac{1}{2}$. Whilst it makes that claim, it never further shows/elaborates as to why this is the case.

Now I am trying to replicate this result but am failing miserably - I'm specifically interested in the case where $k=2$ and $\alpha=3$ - so showing absolute continuity for those two values would be sufficient for me.

NOTE: There is one thing that I *really* don't understand here, and it would be absolutely amazing if somebody could clear this up:
My understanding is that if a complex function, in this case $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{2\pi in^kx}}{n^\alpha}$ is absolutely continuous, then the real part of this function, in this case $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(2\pi n^kx)}{n^\alpha}$, should also be absolutely continuous.

For my case where $k=2$ and $\alpha=3$, the term-wise derivative of the real part equals $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2\pi n^2x)}{n}$. I previously hoped to show that this derivative is well defined, which led to this question I asked on this platform: [Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n^2x)}{n}$ uniformly convergent on $(0,\pi)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4206517/is-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sinn2xn-uniformly-convergent-on-0-pi)

For this series, [metamorphy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/543769/metamorphy) was able to show that it diverges on the dense subset $(0,\pi)$. Now as I understand a function that is absolutely continuous must have a derivative almost everywhere, meaning that those two statements:

1. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i2\pi n^2x}}{n^3}$ is absolutely continuous
2. $\frac{d}{dx}\left[\Re \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{in^2x}}{n^3}\right)\right] $ diverges on the dense subset $(0,\pi)$

Should contradict each other.

I would be more than thankful if someone could help me clear up my misconceptions here/show me how it can be shown that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i2\pi n^2x}}{n^3}$ is actually absolutely continuous! Thanks so much in advance already!

Comment: Do you know about the theory of Fourier series (especially Plancherel's theorem)? This should allow you to show that the derivative of your function belongs to $L^2 \subset L^1$ so that the function is absolutely continuous. Furthermore, note that a dense set can still have measure zero (i.e., the series can diverge on a dense set but still convergence almost everywhere).

Comment: Hey, my main background is in computer science so I know what Fourier series are, but am not knowledgeable about much theory on it - so I don't really know anything about Plancherel's theorem either. 
I'll try to read up on it a bit to see if I can solve it though, thanks a lot for the pointers!